# Ignore Certain Strings

Tags: c, string

I have some C code which reads in the contents of a HTML form from STDIN and, at the moment tokenizes the string.

```
fgets(formip, 1024, stdin);

pch = strtok (formip,"=&");
while (pch != NULL)
{
    printf ("%s\n",pch);
    pch = strtok (NULL, "=&");
    printf ("<br>\n");
}
```

This produces output like this:

```
checkbox,checked,value,2
checkbox,checked,value,3
```

Does anyone know how can I expand this to not write the "checkbox" or "value" strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) to check if the strings are equal or not, it is important not to skip the next call to `strtok` otherwise you will end up in an infinite loop:

```
while (pch != NULL  )
{
    if( strcmp( pch, "value") != 0 && strcmp(pch, "checkbox") != 0)
    {  
       printf ("%s\n",pch);
       printf ("<br>\n");
    }
    pch = strtok (NULL, "=&");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some code that compares, and skips those unwanted strings before printing:

```
while(pch != NULL)
{
  if(strcmp(pch, "checkbox") == 0 || strcmp(pch, "value") == 0)
    continue;
}
```

Comment: If this is done at the top of the loop and you skip the next call to `strtok` you will have an infinite loop.